# angularJS manage one of the input value depends on another`s value

Tags: html, angularjs, input

I want to manage requirement if either of input has any value second of them has to fill like that in angularJS

[image]

Please help me what kind of approaches are the best in angular way!

Here is my code

```
            <div class="form-group recipe_item" ng-repeat="recipe in pc.recipes">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Select Product</label>

                <div class="col-sm-8" ng-controller="ProductCtrl as pc">
                    <select class="form-control" ng-model="recipe.partId"
                            ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in pc.products"
                            >
                        <option value="">-- choose product --</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label id="lbl_qty" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Quantity</label>

                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="recipe.qty" {{isValidNumber(recipe.partId)}}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and my controller

```
$scope.isValidNumber = (number) =>
        return number > 0
```

Comment: you ask for dynamic requirement like you should fill some field if another has some value? or you should field first field before second one?

Comment: It doesn't matter each of them should be filled first.

Comment: like in your image, if name field has value then you should select measure but if name has no value then you can leave it empty?

Comment: if each of them has any value second one also should be filled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `ng-required`... this is what you need... here is [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/CQvs7uL3uOW7118HwC1y?p=preview) example...

I updated example by adding angularjs form controller and here is [form controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) documentation for more details...

Comment: It seems to me it works fine but i need to add "required" parameter to inputs.How can i do that for inputs? For example "<span>{{model ? "yes;" : "no;"}}</span>" works fine.

Comment: yes it is common way to do it, but if you use it in a form you can get error, required etc... here is form controller document https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form

Comment: @nAkhmedov check updated answer for your second question... ng-required dynamically add required if expression in ng-required is true...